# How to Install the ArcGIS JavaScript 3.2 API library on an IIS Web Server?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, development, deployment

I would like to deploy Server API for JavaScript 3.2 in my server to use it in my asp.net project instead of connect to server

What are the steps to be followed in deploying it to a local WebServer?

Comment: You can download it from here: http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/

Comment: What is your question exactly? Have you downloaded the sdk? Have you read the readme that comes along with it? What Issue have you run into?

Comment: i already download put i don't know how to use it . i take copy of folder and put it in C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: i download arcgis_js_v32_api and read install.html and copy folder in wwwroot and when use my url in my server map not appear ??

Comment: Have you made the changes that the readme tells you to do? Can you access the JavaScript directly by putting the required URL in the browser?

Comment: i didn't found [HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI] in init.js to replace it by my server. i copy folder in wwwroot only. what changes i do to solve this problem please???

Comment: See my answer. Use a good text editor to search and replace the text. It is definitely there. I just did this procedure last week for my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps in installation of a local version of ArcGIS JavaScript API are as follows:

1. You can download the required version from here: http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/
2. Extract the files to your Webserver.
3. Read the Installation instructions given in the Readme, and do the required edits. I would suggest that you use a good Text Editor with advanced Search & Replace functionality (like Notepad++).
4. Confirm that the JavaScript files are accessible (By entering their URL in your Browser).
5. Make the test app, as indicated in the Readme, to test that the deployment is successful.
6. ???
7. *PROFIT!!!*